# Enable WooCommerce logging with Wordpress on Google App Engine Flex PHP

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, woocommerce

I have WooCommerce running with Wordpress deployed on Google App Engine Flex PHP environment, which is a Read-Only file system.

*WooCommerce > System Status // WordPress environment -- Log directory writable:*
shows
`To allow logging, make gs://MY-BUCKET.appspot.com/1/wc-logs/ writable or define a custom WC_LOG_DIR`

**To enable logging**, do I want to...

1. Make the GCS Bucket writable, keeping in mind GCS Bucket objects cannot be appended to, only overwritten? Or...
2. Redirect logs to `stdout` and `stderr` and use Stackdriver Logging for my Google Cloud Platform project instead?

How do I implement either choice?

Binary files like uploads to the Wordpress Media Library are stored as objects in a Google Cloud Storage Bucket and served from `https://storage.googleapis.com/MY_BUCKET.appspot.com/1/FILE-NAME.jpg` --
 this is managed in WordPress by Google Cloud Storage plugin.

And I can utilize the Google API and Cloud Services php libraries.

But I don't understand enough of the principles and specifics of the environment to string everything together.

Answer (score 0):

On App Engine Flex, some directories are still writeable. For example `/tmp` is always writeable. Maybe you can just use `/tmp`? However, if you run multiple instances, the logs on a single server won't be available on other servers.

Comment: @Matsuo I found PHP Exception is represented as object sometimes and string in other times (shown in stackdriver logging), do you have any recommendation to get Exception as object for all PHP Exceptions? (I prefer use Exception object instead of string, because object has more information, even though there are a lot of Exceptions represented by string in logs)